# What is a bordism and the theories of bordisms for?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I understand what they are and I see that they are used in TQFT for quantum gravity but I don't understand what they are for in algebraic topology and what are the following goals in bordism theory

Comment: I would say two things,  the definition of cobordism is very natural and geometric so I guess many people study it out of curiosity.

The second point is slightly mor vague.  Many topological invariants only depend on the (cobordism) class (the exact ones will depend on which category you work in). Studying how these topological invariants behave with respect the cobordism ring and seeing has been extremely fruitful. Many fundamental topological invariants can be written as power series over the cobordism ring, 

To read more about this I suggest the book "manifolds and modular forms"

Comment: @NickL I am a Mexican physicist and the truth is that I have not been able to complete my course on chern simmons for quantizations, many speak of written gromov invariants, chern, ect, what I have never been able to understand is why they are invariants? Before what are they invariants?